# Issue with returning uints in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, cryptocurrency

So I've started learning solidity and I want to make a function that return the total amount of coins created.

Here are the important parts of the contract

```
address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    uint totalSupply;


function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
require(msg.sender == owner);
        // balances[receiver] = balances[receiver] + amount;
        totalSupply += amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }

function CheckTotalSupply(uint supply) public {
        returns supply;
    }
```

When I compile it gives me this error.

```
ParserError: Expected primary expression.
--> subcurrency.sol:47:9:
|
47 | returns supply;
| ^^^^^^^
```

What is the issue?

Also if I use return it says

```
TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
--> subcurrency.sol:47:9:
|
47 | return supply;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `return` instead of `returns`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use standard ERC20 or whatever kind of token you want to create. [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/) is the standard ERC20 contract. To use the standard ERC20 contract, you have to import it and your token contract should inherit it. Like this:

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract YOUR_TOKEN_CONTRACT is ERC20{

   constructor() ERC20(YOU_TOKEN_NAME, YOUR_TOKEN_SYMBOL){
   //code here
   //for example _mint(msg.sender, 100000);
   }
   //code here
}
```

Standard ERC20 contract has a function to return total supply called `totalSupply()`. So it makes it easier to write token contracts.

Also you have syntax error in your code!

To return a value you have to follow this syntax:

```
function CheckTotalSupply(uint supply) public retuns(uint){
        return supply;//                      ^ this is returns with (s) at its end
      //^ this is return whitout (s) at its end
    }
```

in `retuns` you specify what kind of variable you want to return then in `return` you return the values in order you specified in `returns`